# Does qmail-ldap provide functionality equivalent to the qmail validrcptto patch?

Tags: linux, ldap, email

We are using qmail with the validrcptto patch to route incoming mail to our Domino server. However, that requires us to maintain the validrcptto file with the list of all allowed email addresses.

Since Domino provides an LDAP directory, does qmail-ldap provide functionnality to lookup valid rcpt to addresses in the Domino directory instead of the validrcptto file, so that we wouldn't have to maintain that extra list ?

We have about 150~200 users, so is setting up qmail-ldap worth the extra mile if it can verify addresses in the LDAP directory ?

If anyone has experience with qmail-ldap and its setup, I'd be glad to hear from you.

Comment: Is there a reason your using Qmail? If it's just doing address validation and forwarding, you should be able to set a modern MTA (Postfix, Exim) to do what you want in less than an hour.

Comment: Yes, there is. We are indeed using Qmail to validate and forward mail to Domino on our proxy/router box, which is a custom built Debian distro, provided by an external security company. So I don't have much control over that, as it would violate our contract with them. I ended up writing a shell script that extracts mail adresses from Domino's LDAP and rebuilds the ValidRCPTTO file if necessary, and placed it in crontab.